# Run a parallel python script from C

Tags: python, c, mpi

I have a python script that I normally run in parallel by using the command

```
mpirun -n x script.py
```

Is it possible to embed this parallelised python code in a C program?

I.e. python.org describes how to embed python code in C [here](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html).  E.g.

```
#include <Python.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);  /* optional but recommended */
  Py_Initialize();
  PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime\n"
                      "print 'Today is',ctime(time())\n");
  Py_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to do something similar if, instead of reporting the time, the code was parallel python code?  My stopgap solution is

```
sprintf(command_string,"mpirun -n x python script.py");
system(command_string);
```

but this will not be an option soon.

Thanks,
Thomas

Comment: "but this will not be an option soon."  Why not?

Answer (score 0):

Does your script use MPI at all (e.g. mpi4py)?

You can run Python inside your C program as you have described, and in [other ways](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html), but if the program makes MPI calls, the executable must be linked to an MPI library.

One possibility would be to run the C program with mpirun. Just compile and run as before:

```
mpirun -n x cprog
```

Inside your C program, you could execute the Python code, which would already be in a parallel context (because the C program is now running in parallel). There is potentially extra work here if you actually require the use of the MPI library.

If you do require MPI calls (e.g. MPI_Comm_rank and so forth), you could link in the MPI library to your C program, execute it as above, call whatever MPI commands you require at the C level, then pass the data to your Python code through the Python C API.

If you don't require MPI calls (so you are just using mpirun to launch many versions of a Python script on your cluster), then just `mpirun`ing your C program would work.

You can also launch the C program in parallel, and use MPI in the Python script, but keep in mind that you should `MPI_Init` and `MPI_Finalize` all in the Python layer (and not in Python and C).

If you must run the C program in serial, I think you would need to shell out to launch the parallel job.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,
My script uses functions from a library written for serial and parallel.  I.e. I can either use
    "python script.py"
or
    "mpirun -n 4 python script.py"
How MPI is called specifically is hidden from me, it is all handled in the library I import (dolfin).  The functions "know" if I am using mpirun or not.

I was under the impression that "mpirun -n x cprog" would just result in the python code being run in serial, on each  of the x processors.  I did not know it would actually inherit mpirun.